# How to insert a barcode into the lower continuum

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose.words

I have a barcode creation code and the footer

```
BarcodeGenerator generator = new BarcodeGenerator(EncodeTypes.Code128, "1234567890");

Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
generator.Save(ms, BarCodeImageFormat.Png);

Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document();

DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.InsertImage(ms,
    RelativeHorizontalPosition.Margin,
    0,
    RelativeVerticalPosition.Margin,
    400,
    200,
    100,
    WrapType.Square);
```

There are questions

1. How to create a right footer, now it is being created on the left

Now the barcode is inserted in an arbitrary place.I use aspose.words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DocumentBuilder.MoveToHeaderFooter` to move cursor into the footer and then use `ParagraphAlignment.Right` to place barcode at right. See the following code:

```cs
BarcodeGenerator generator = new BarcodeGenerator(EncodeTypes.Code128, "1234567890");
Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
generator.Save(ms, BarCodeImageFormat.Png);

Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
// Move DocumentBuilder into the footer.
builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary);
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
builder.InsertImage(ms);

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

Comment: And how do I create a footer on only 1 page?

Comment: Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(dataDir + "sample2.docx");

I need to insert a barcode on an existing document and now he puts the barcode in the right footer, on all pages.

Comment: If you need to insert footer only on the first page, you should use first page footer: `builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.FooterFirst);`

Comment: I have tried this code.But then there is no barcode and footer at all.

Comment: I would suggest you to post the problem along with input and output document in [Aspose.Words support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8/).